# Get user's OneDrive ID using MSGraph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to connect to the MSGraph API to get the user's drive ID but the server keeps saying

```
There has been an error authenticating the request
```

I've already ensured my token asks for the necessary permissions, but I just can't get the API to return what I need.

The endpoint I'm trying to call is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive
```

The permissions I'm including in the token are

```
Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Sites.Read.All 
Sites.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.ReadBasic.All profile openid email
```

Comment: What's the type of those permissions? Delegated or Application?

Comment: The problem was that I was not a group Administrator, but it was Application permission. Anyway, thank you very much